# Hover over anchor to display images in second div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

how can i hover the a tags with the classname hovernaviitem and display  the class imagecontainer with 4 images which belong to the 4  tags ??sorry for my bad english.

**** EDIT: do i have to hide the class imagecontainer when the html loads ? because i only want to display the imagecontainer when hovering over the anchor tags.

```
**THE HTML** 

<div class="list-group">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item active hovernaviitem">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">lorem fhaowidnioanduoabnuid baui</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item hovernaviitem">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">lorem fhaowidnioanduoabnuid baui</p>
</a>    
<a href="#" class="list-group-item hovernaviitem">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">lorem fhaowidnioanduoabnuid baui</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item hovernaviitem">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">lorem fhaowidnioanduoabnuid baui</p>
</a>    
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-md-6">
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="img/galerie/1video.png" class="img-responsive hoverimg" alt="Responsive      image">
<img src="img/galerie/1video1.png" class="img-responsive hoverimg" alt="Responsive image">
<img src="img/galerie/1video2.png" class="img-responsive hoverimg" alt="Responsive image2">
</div>


</div>
</div> <!-- row -->
```

**THE JS**

```
$('.hoverimg').onClick(function(){
$('.imagecontainer').show();

});
```

Comment: Where are the 'tags' in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use hover:

```
$( "hoverimg" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('.imagecontainer').show();
  }, function() {
    $('.imagecontainer').hide();
  }
);
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

In your case (I suppose you want to switch between the images and not to show them all at once), you would need a way to know which link triggers which image, which you can do by adding classes:

```
  <div class="imagecontainer">
  <img src="img/galerie/1video.png" class="img-responsive hoverimg hoverimg1" alt="Responsive image">
  <img src="img/galerie/1video1.png" class="img-responsive hoverimg hoverimg2" alt="Responsive image">
  <img src="img/galerie/1video2.png" class="img-responsive hoverimg hoverimg3" alt="Responsive image">
  </div>


<div class="list-group">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item active hovernaviitem1">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">lorem fhaowidnioanduoabnuid baui</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item hovernaviitem2">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">lorem fhaowidnioanduoabnuid baui</p>
</a>    
<a href="#" class="list-group-item hovernaviitem3">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">lorem fhaowidnioanduoabnuid baui</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item hovernaviitem4">
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">lorem fhaowidnioanduoabnuid baui</p>
</a>    
</div>
```

.

```
$( "hovernaviitem1" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('.imagecontainer1').show();
  }, function() {
    $('.imagecontainer1').hide();
  }
);
//...
```

Or you could can simply keep them in a specfic order and use

```
$(function(){
    $( ".hover-img-link" ).hover(
      function() {
        var index =  $(this).index();
         $('.imgs img').eq(index-1).show();
      }, function() {
        var index =  $(this).index();
         $('.imgs img').eq(index-1).hide();
      }
    );
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/q1UY6XAwUcLRpAFECG2i

Comment: What i don´t get is, how to set the imagecontainer in html when the document is loaded. the document shows all 4 images and not only 1 when hovered. @ hugo, evtl kannst du mir das auch auf Deutsch erklären, wäre für mich warscheinlich einfacher :)

Comment: That would be bad manners, as most people here wouldn't understand us ;). I would recommend you to use the last snippet I posted (check out the plunker link to see how it works).

Comment: yay it works men !!! thanks :). i had a bracket with one space in my js file ..... took me one hour to find this little devil :)

one last question, can u tell me what eq.(index-1) means ?

Comment: When you have a jquery-selector often times have more than 1 match. eq allows you to select a specific match starting from 0. See: http://api.jquery.com/eq/ index on the other hand starts from 1. This why the -1 is there. 
If the answer did work out for you, it would be nice, if you could mark it as the accepted answer, so others know that it already has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event

```
$( ".hovernaviitem" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('.imagecontainer').show();
  }, function() {
    $('.imagecontainer').hide();
  }
);
```